# what is the difference between LINQ and ADO.net

Tags: linq, ado.net

what is the difference between LINQ and ADO.net

Comment: @mxmissible: Although poorly framed, this question would hardly fall in the `lmgtfy category`.  LINQ with its many providers (LINQ-to-Entities, -to-SQL, to-XML...) is a rather broad and abstract topic and it might take a lot of googling and reading before one would get the answer to this question (or worse: one without the  minimal background could get utterly confused as to what LINQ is and isn't).

Answer (score 4):

Linq is a language feature (Language INtegrated Query) that allows for querying of objects. It is often conflated with Linq to Sql, which is a series of extension methods and other code that allows querying of a Sql Server database using Linq statements.

You can write a Linq provider to query any kind of datasource, for example, there is a Linq to Amazon provider that allows you to retrieve results from Amazon's public API.

ADO.Net is series of technologies for retrieving data, I suggest starting here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ADO.NET

Answer (score 3):

I think you probably mean LINQ-to-SQL. ADO.NET is the bare bones of talking to a Database, so you need to set up the DataTables, DataReaders, etc. yourself. This includes iterating through our tables, setting up your connections, transactions, etc.

LINQ-to-SQL is an ORM (Object Relationship Mapper)  which allows you to view your data as business objects, instead of collections of data in DataTables. LINQ-to-SQL works with ADO.NET under the hood. Much easier!

LINQ is the expression syntax used by LINQ-to-SQL to query tables, eg

```
ClientSet.Where(q=>q.ID==1).First();
```

Answer (score 0):

LINQ to SQL actually stands for LINQ to 'databases that use SQL' or in other words LINQ for the relational data model.  LINQ to Entities means LINQ for the Entity-Data-Model which is a kind of a relational++ model.

More info:

http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/gilf/archive/2008/04/20/linq-to-sql-vs-entity-framework.aspx

Comment: No, Linq to SQL is not for "databases that use SQL". It's for SQL Server only, not other databases. Entity Framework, on the other hand, can work with other DMBS

Answer (score 0):

ADO.NET

1. It is a part of .NET Framework since .NET Framework 1.0
2. SqlConnection/OleDbConnection is used for database connectivity.
3. Difficult to debug and cause syntax errors at run-time.
4. It has full type checking at run-time and not IntelliSense support in Visual
   Studio, since it used the T-SQL to query the database.

LINQ

1. It is a part of .NET Framework since .NET Framework 3.5
2. We can use context for database connectivity.
3. Easy to debug and cause syntax errors at compile-time.
4. It has full type checking at compile-time and IntelliSense support in Visual Studio, since it used the .NET Framework languages like C# and VB.